# How do I set up bind mounts on startup correctly in the systemd world?

Tags: systemd, fstab, bind-mount

`systemd`, trying to be smart, parallelizes mounting entries of `/etc/fstab`. Unfortunately, this randomly messes up bind mounts:

A look at my `fstab`, cleaned up a bit:

```
$ grep -Ev 'ntfs|swap|#' /etc/fstab
UUID=3cbb59fd-ff2c-47ed-955f-e4945b5c95b6   /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1
UUID=2d7b3de8-782b-4981-9db6-a4b9a6d45cac   /home/muru/devel    ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 2
UUID=38d31418-ed63-49e8-b11b-df90da4833e2   /home/muru/var  btrfs       rw,relatime,space_cache 0 0
UUID=77307ad0-35e1-439b-8fe2-07a7bb5376b2   /mnt        ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 2
/home/muru /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie/home/muru none bind 0 0
/home/muru /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie-test/home/muru none bind 0 0
/home/muru/devel /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie/home/muru/devel none bind 0 0
/home/muru/devel /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie-test/home/muru/devel none bind 0 0
```

And my actual mounts:

```
$ mount | grep ^/dev/ | grep -Ev 'fuseblk|run'
/dev/sdb1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda7 on /home/muru/devel type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb1 on /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie/home/muru type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb1 on /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie-test/home/muru type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda7 on /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie-test/home/muru/devel type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda7 on /home/muru/devel type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda7 on /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie/home/muru/devel type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda7 on /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie/home/muru/devel type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda7 on /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie-test/home/muru/devel type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda7 on /home/muru/devel type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda7 on /home/muru/devel type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb8 on /home/muru/var type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache)
/dev/sdb8 on /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie/home/muru/var type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache)
/dev/sdb8 on /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie-test/home/muru/var type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache)
```

As you can see, it *looks* like the mounts have been done successfully. But, the effect:

```
$ ls -l /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie/home/
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun 20 20:36 muru/
$ ls -l /home/muru/devel/debian/jessie/home/muru/
total 0
```

I think this is due to random ordering of the mounts. If that's the case, how do I ensure an order? Do I have to use something other than `fstab`? If that's not the case, what might have caused it?

I'm using Arch Linux.

```
$ systemctl --version
systemd 221
+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID -ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
```

Comment: fstab's fine, but fuse could be an issue. there are `.mount` units, too, though.

Comment: You're bind mounting `/home/muru` to `/home/muru/.../child/path`? That's going to be problematic no matter *who* does the mounting. You need first to configure some path within as *unbindable*. The docs are [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt).

Comment: @mikeserv Why not? It worked fine enough on a non-systemd system or when I manually ran the `mount -o bind` commands. I'm not going to run any recursive commands on these paths.

Comment: Ok, but the docs I linked to were the kernel docs on shared subtrees - not systemd docs. I don't know why systemd wouldn't do it correctly - it always handles my fstab binds correctly. I don't bind any fs loops, though.

Comment: I have a circular mount `/` -> `/d/root` and it seems to work (Debian 8).  I can't work out how your result could follow from a mis-ordering.  The mounts shown for non-existent directories are odd, it's almost as if they're still there but an empty filesystem was mounted on top later on.   Can I suggest a) `findmnt` (it shows the source directory of binds as well) b) looking at inode numbers using `stat`, they should match for both the target and source directory.

Comment: I'd mounted manually after posting the question, so `findmnt` output maybe stranger than it has to be: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11898548/

Answer (score 8):

Arnout's solution worked for me but there's a little mistake in it. Bind mounts in fstab must be like this (he swapped "bind" and "none"). Cf fstab manual.

```
# /etc/fstab
/home/var /var none x-systemd.requires=/home,x-systemd.automount,bind 0 0
```

Systemd mount reference is here : https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html

Answer (score 5):

More than a year later with the version of systemd (229)now shipping with ubuntu 16.04 there is support in fstab for dependency mounting like this.

so it's as easy as doing this.

```
# /etc/fstab
/home/var /var bind x-systemd.requires=/home,x-systemd.automount,none 0 0
```

got the idea from this post
https://copyninja.info/blog/systemd_automount_entry.html

`1/22/2021` seems the line above is not correct (ever?).  I have been using this below and it works.  In this case to mount /opt to an alternative drive.  I have not used `auto` as was suggested in comments

```
/mnt/data/opt   /opt    x-systemd.requires=/mnt/data,x-systemd.automount,none   bind    0   0
```

Comment: +-1, but way too late to solve that particular problem. Maybe I'll use a similar setup in the future and test this out.

Comment: not working https://pastebin.com/raw/Ev6PaXAW

Comment: This continues to work for me with new installs and later versions of systemd.  maybe try getting a single bind mount to work first (also you may be editing the wrong file based on comments in file.  Alternatively @srghama as to your particular application you may consider editing this file ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs instead.  Not the same as bind mounts but may address your use case.

Comment: your columns are wrong, change needed: filesystem column should be "auto" and "bind" should be in "options" column, i.e change "bind" to "auto bind," (not the comma)

Comment: @ glen ur right that is not what I am using now. But not exactly as you suggested.  I have edited my post

Answer (score 2):

You could also make unit files for these bind mounts:

```
[Mount]
What=/home/muru
Where=/where/ever/you/want/to
Type=none
Options=bind

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The trick here is specifying "Type" as `none`, and "Options" as `bind`, similar to how you do it on cmd-line.

You can add wants/requires clauses, if the automatic ordering by dependency should fail.